# How to include Multiple GridView in a Activity(use ScrollView), just displayed one row?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I want to make Activity like this using GridView.
And this Activity have only one scrollbar include all text & gridview.

for it, using scrollview.

```
<ScrollView>
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<TextView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<GridView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<TextView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<GridView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I wrote xml and class like attached using ScrollView to have only one 
scroll.
GridView has `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`, but just visible one row.
And each GridView has scroll.
Same result layout_height was changed to wrap_content.

Is it bug? or Do I have some mistake? or Is it impossible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the parameter weight :
0 for TextView
1 for GridView

Comment: I had resolve this problem, i use TextView and List,iterate this List and set the data on TextView. thanks!